# How to integrate forms of several entities? Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I need to merge table 'fos_user' and 'institution'.And I need to display registration form from both entities.
I have a problem with FOSUserBundle.
I created new properties in User class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

protected $workPhone;

protected $adminPhone;

protected $name;

protected $adress;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();   
}

public function setAdress($adress)
{
    $this->adress = $adress;
}

 public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

 public function setWorkPhone($workPhone)
{
    $this->workPhone = $workPhone;
}

 public function setAdminPhone($adminPhone)
{
    $this->adminPhone = $adminPhone;
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function getAdress()
{
    return $this->adress;
}

public function getWorkPhone()
{
    return $this->workPhone;
}

public function getAdminPhone()
{
    return $this->adminPhone;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

And I have entity Institution, which I want merge.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_institution", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $idInstitution;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="work_phone", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $workPhone;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="admin_phone", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $adminPhone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="adress", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $adress;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\FosUser
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\FosUser")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_fos_user", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idFosUser;

/**
 * Get idInstitution
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getIdInstitution()
{
    return $this->idInstitution;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Institution
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set workPhone
 *
 * @param integer $workPhone
 * @return Institution
 */
public function setWorkPhone($workPhone)
{
    $this->workPhone = $workPhone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get workPhone
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getWorkPhone()
{
    return $this->workPhone;
}

/**
 * Set adminPhone
 *
 * @param integer $adminPhone
 * @return Institution
 */
public function setAdminPhone($adminPhone)
{
    $this->adminPhone = $adminPhone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get adminPhone
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getAdminPhone()
{
    return $this->adminPhone;
}

/**
 * Set adress
 *
 * @param string $adress
 * @return Institution
 */
public function setAdress($adress)
{
    $this->adress = $adress;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get adress
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAdress()
{
    return $this->adress;
}

/**
 * Set idFosUser
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\FosUser $idFosUser
 * @return Institution
 */
public function setIdFosUser($idFosUser = null)
{
    $this->idFosUser = $idFosUser;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idFosUser
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\FosUser 
 */
public function getIdFosUser()
{
    return $this->idFosUser;
}
```

This is pert of InstitutionManager where I want save Entity, and this is like service now:

```
public function createNewEntity($user)
{
    $entity = new Institution();
    $entity->setName($user->getName());
    $entity->setAdminPhone($user->getAdminPhone());
    $entity->setWorkPhone($user->getWorkPhone());
    $entity->setAdress($user->getAdress());
    $entity->setidFosUser($user->getId());

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

}
```

And hear override RegistrationController:

```
public function registerAction()
{
    $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
    $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

    $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
    if ($process) {
        $user = $form->getData();

        $authUser = false;
        if ($confirmationEnabled) {
            $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
            $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
        } else {
            $authUser = true;
            $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
        }

        $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');


        $institutionManager = $this->container->get('institution_manager');
        $institution = $institutionManager->createNewEntity($user);

        $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

        if ($authUser) {
            $this->authenticateUser($user, $response);
        }

        return $response;
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

services.yml:

```
services:
    institution_manager:
        class: AppBundle\Lib\Manager\InstitutionManager
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager ]
```

Comment: Post your controller code please

Comment: I update post. If anything more - just tell me!TX

Answer (score 2):

Your InstitutationController is not being properly initialized.  There is a setContainer method which the router calls to, well, set the container.  getDoctrine in turn needs the container, hence the null object error.

A simple hack would be to call the setContainer method yourself:

```
$entity = new InstitutionController();
$entity->setContainer($this->container);
$entity->createNewEntity($user);
```

But it's a hack you should do some redesigning.  What you are calling a controller is not a controller at all.  It's a service, maybe a sort of a factory or manager.  Sort of like the FOS UserManager.

So read up on how to define a service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

It takes a bit of research but once you understand the process then services will become second nature.  You will inject the doctrine entity manager directly into your service.

```
class InstitutionManager
{
protected $entityManager;

public function __construct($entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
public function createNewEntity($user)
{
    $entity = new Institution();
    $entity->setName($user->getName());
    $entity->setAdminPhone($user->getAdminPhone());
    $entity->setWorkPhone($user->getWorkPhone());
    $entity->setAdress($user->getAdress());
    $entity->setidFosUser($user->getId());

    $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return $entity;
}
```

I will leave services.yml up to you.  The entity manager service id is doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager

Your controller would then look like:

```
$institutionManager = $this->get('institution_manager');
$institution = $institutionManager->create($user);
```

You will also want to rethink how you are relating the user object.  The userId stuff is a no no.  You will want to make a one-to-one relation between $institution and $user.  But that is really a different topic.

Enjoy.

Comment: I did all as you said, but now I have error _Call to a member function persist() on string_ in function createNewEntity(). `$this->entityManager->persist($entity);`

Comment: I am guessing your forgot the @ symbol when injecting the entity manager service: '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'.  If not then update your question with your services.yml definition.

Comment: It's easy to update a question.  Scroll up to your question then press the edit button.  Delete the existing code and post the updated Manager, service definition, relevant controller lines and the new error message.

Comment: Read the comment you just posted.  Do you think anybody can make sense of your services.yml?  Update your question so we can see it properly formatted.  And don't use a parameter for the entity manager service id.

Comment: You posted the service which looks okay.  Now can you give us a hint as to what "it`s not work" means in this context?

Comment: I get _Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given_.

Comment: Progress!  See the last line in my answer.  Your objects are all screwed up.  Read the chapter on doctrine to see how object relations are managed.  Completely different issue.  But at least your service works.